# Como criar uma animação para uma propriedade de GraphicsEffect em PyQt5?

Tags: animação, pyqt-5, opacity

Eu criei uma `Label` para fazer uma apresentação de slides e quero criar um efeito de transição *fading* entre uma imagem e outra.

Para fazer esse efeito, eu quero definir uma opacidade de `1.0` à `0.0` na minha `Label`. Até o momento, eu estou utilizando o código abaixo para alterar a opacidade:

```
opacity_effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
opacity_effect.setOpacity(0.3)
label.setGraphicsEffect(opacity_effect)
```

Pesquisando na internet sobre animações em PyQt5, eu descobri apenas a classe `QtCore.QPropertyAnimation`, mas que parece não servir para esse caso. Minha dúvida é: como eu posso criar uma animação para as propriedades de `GraphicsEffect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QPropertyAnimation pode ser usado nesse caso sim, veja o exemplo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Teste(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100,100,700,500)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.btn = QPushButton('start',self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self._efeito)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.efeito = QGraphicsOpacityEffect(self.label)
        self.efeito.setOpacity(1)
        self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.efeito)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background:red")
        self.label.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.efeito = QPropertyAnimation(self.efeito,b'opacity')
    
    def _efeito(self):
    
        self.efeito.setDuration(1000)
        self.efeito.setStartValue(1)
        self.efeito.setEndValue(0)
    
        self.efeito.start()


app = QApplication([])
w = Teste()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```